# Gradle - Eclipse LinkedResource creates empty folder

Tags: eclipse, gradle

I am having trouble with Gradle linkedResource. It creates the 'correct' folder in the correct place, however, it's empty - there are no resources 'ported'. I've tried with locationUri but to no avail. Weirdly, there are no errors reported with neither eclipse nor from the console when running `gradle eclipse`

```
project {
        // Linked Resources     
        linkedResource name: 'src/main/java/com/software/main', type: '2', location: '../project2/src/main/java/com/software/main'
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (the snippet is not a complete `build.gradle` to reproduce your issue) and show what you actually see in Eclipse plus your `.project` file (because this is where Eclipse stores the linked resources). It's unclear which folder has been actually created (the link or the link target). Please link also to the documentation you followed.

Comment: @howlger I've actually managed to find the issue of my problem :) Gradle did not like how I've put a reference to a file/folder with `../` Instead I had to do `WORKSPACE_LOC` and that solved the issue :)